# Indexed column never get used in sql server

Tags: sql-server

In sql server 2012 i have a table named specialqueue which have 10 column which three of them are indexed and their type is bit

```
tbale specialqueue 

        column1 column2 .....cloumn7  Isconfirmed(bit) IsDeleted(bit) IsSuspended(bit)
```

first i create index on Isconfirmed,IsDeleted,IsSuspended

but actual execution plan of this query was

```
 SELECT IsDeleted,Id,[Description] FROM sim WHERE IsDeleted=0
```

[image]

what i want to do fast is this query

```
SELECT IsDeleted,Id,[Description] FROM sim WHERE IsDeleted=0  AND  IsSuspended =0 AND IsConfirmed = 1
```

but after creating index on

```
  CREATE  INDEX [IX_IsDeleted_IsConfirmed] ON [dbo].[SpecialQueue]
  (
  [IsDeleted],[IsSuspended],[IsConfirmed]
  )
      GO
```

i still get the same execution plan which is **scan** instead of **seek**

how can I improve the performance of above query?

Comment: How useful it is is quite dubious - especially if the statistics show that most of the data is going to be a hit. I wonder whether some form of filtered index may work better.

Comment: i'm going to try that but for now i'm not getting any seek in my execution plan, i have many deadblocks in my websites...

Comment: I made a nonClustered filtered Index but nothing happend CREATE  INDEX [IX_IsDeleted_IsConfirmed] ON [dbo].[Sim]
(
[IsDeleted],[IsSuspended],[IsConfirmed]
)
WHERE IsDeleted = 0 AND IsConfirmed=1 AND IsSuspended=0;

Comment: what are the statistics like? how much of the table meets this condition? how many rows are there in the first place?

Comment: There are near 1M rows in my table. How can i calculate the percentage of occurring this condition? (i create the above index in production and until now(8 hours) i haven't seen any deadlocks)